# get values out of xml file for barchart

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a xml like this:

```
<chart showValues="0" adjustDiv="0" showLabels="1" rotateLabels="1" slantLabels="1" xAxisName="" yAxisMinValue="-1" yAxisMaxValue="2" showYAxisValues="0" numDivLines="0" zeroPlaneAlpha="0" plotSpacePercent="10" plotFillRatio="100" caption="" labelStep="4" numVDivLines="15" vDivLineAlpha="10" animation="1" bgColor="FFFFFF" bgAlpha="0" showBorder="0" borderColor="415D6F" borderThickness="1" canvasBgColor="FFFFFF" canvasBgAlpha="100" canvasBorderColor="545454" canvasBorderAlpha="100" canvasBorderThickness="1" showCanvasBase="1" chartTopMargin="" chartLeftMargin="" chartRightMargin="" chartBottomMargin="-5" labelPadding="5" yAxisValuesPadding="7" hoverCapBgColor="ffffff" hoverCapBorderColor="708290" baseFont="Tahoma" baseFontSize="11" baseFontColor="535454" divLineColor="FFFFFF" divLineAlpha="65" divLineThickness="1" showAlternateHGridColor="0" alternateHGridColor="92CDD6" alternateHGridAlpha="10" legendBgColor="FFFFFF" legendBgAlpha="0" legendBorderColor="415D6F" legendBorderAlpha="50" legendBorderThickness="1" legendShadow="0" legendScrollBgColor="CCCCCC" legendScrollBarColor="CCCCCC" legendScrollBtnColor="999999" useRoundEdges="1">
    <categories>
        <category label="00:00"/>
        <category label="01:00"/>
        <category label="02:00"/>
    </categories>
    <dataset>
        <set value="2" color="8BBA00" alpha="100" toolText="Jan 12 24:00, Normal"/>
        <set value="1" color="8BBA00" alpha="100" toolText="Jan 12 01:00, Warning"/>
        <set value="1" color="8BBA00" alpha="100" toolText="Jan 12 02:00, Warning"/>
    </dataset>
</chart>
```

how can I get the "value" out of it? I need the value for a barchart. 
I think getElementsByTagName() is not working in ths context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like :

```
   var sets = getElementsByTagName("set");
   for(i = 0;i < sets.length; i++)
   {
          var value = sets[i].getAttribute("value");
          // [...]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xmlString );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
$xml.find( "set" ).each(function(index,node){
    console.log(node.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

working Example [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xw1eja2r/)

Comment: This one works with jquery. I think the OP didn't assume he uses it. :)